# LaTeXで部分的なフォントの変更（部分的に整形可能な等幅フォント組みにしたい）

Tags: font, latex

LaTeXで部分的にフォントを変える方法を探しています．具体的にはMacOSに標準で付属しているOsaka regular monoで部分的に組みたいと考えています．

おそらく，\texttt{...}によって呼び出されるフォントを変える方法があるのではないかと考えているのですが，フォントマップなどのことがきちんとわからないため頓挫しています．また，\texttt{...}で等幅フォントをよびだせるようにした場合，その部分は自動で行長の調整などがされずに等幅のまま組まれるのかどうか，といったこともご教授いただけたらと思います．

なお，タイトルに「整形可能な」とあるのは，verbatimやjverbatimといった環境も試し，一応等幅にはできることがわかった（等幅かつ，英数字が全角文字の半分の幅になってほしい）のですが，これだと下線を引いたりすることができないので，目的を達せなかったためです．

参考：
[トランスクリプションのための記号](http://www.meijigakuin.ac.jp/~aug/transsym.htm)

上記リンクにあるような，話された言葉をできるだけそのときの情報を失わずに書きおこすことが目指される分野の研究でLaTeXを利用しています．スペースなどにも意味を持たせるため，幅が揃っていることが望ましく，また下線が引ける必要がある（太字は無理かもしれませんね…）のです．ちなみに他の研究者はwordなどwysiwygツールを利用するか，それらを利用して作成した書き起こしを図にして貼り付けている場合が多いと思います．

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX におけるフォントの設定は使用する TeX エンジンによって大きく異なります（また，OS のバージョンによっても異なります）．特に使用する TeX エンジンについてこだわりがないのであれば，LuaTeX を用いると簡単にフォント設定を行うことができます．

具体的には，次の雛形の `<font file>` に使用したいフォントファイル名を入れるだけで（例：`Osaka`）デフォルトのタイプライタ体を変更できます．

```
\documentclass{ltjsarticle}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{<font file>}

\begin{document}

\texttt{Hello, World!}

\end{document}
```

ただし，最近の macOS 標準のフォントは，フォントファイルの配置位置が特殊なので，事前にコマンドラインで以下のコマンドを実行しておく必要があるかもしれません（このあたりの事情は macOS のバージョンによって異なります）．

```
sudo cjk-gs-integrate --link-texmf --force
```

参考：http://doratex.hatenablog.jp/entry/20161202/1480665692

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます．また詳しい雛形もお示しいただきありがとうございます．TeXエンジンについてはこだわりはないのですが，ハードルが高いように思われて手を出さずにおりました．これを機会に勉強してみたいと思います．

Answer (score 2):

「整形可能な」の部分について、LaTeXでスペースや改行を入力したように出力し、なおかつフォントスタイルや下線などを利用したいという場合には、下記のようなverbatim環境の代替手段があります（どれもすでにインストールされているはずなので、usepackageすれば使えます）。

- allttパッケージのalltt環境
- listingsパッケージのlstlisting環境
- fancyvrbパッケージのVerbatim環境
- fvex­traパッケージのVerbatim環境

基本的には下に挙げたものほど多機能と思ってください。が、それぞれ一長一短あり、使い方にも癖があるので、目的の用途にはalltt環境で十分な気がします。

フォントについて補足すると、TeX（日本語だとpTeXかも）は、OSにインストールされているフォントを利用するわけではなく、原則としてTeXのシステムから見えるものだけを使います。OsakaはTeXのシステムから見えるフォントではないので、そのままは使えない、というのが答えになります。ただし、LuaTeX（あるいはXeTeX）というTeXとは別のTeXエンジンであれば、OSにインストールされているフォントを比較的容易に利用する手段があるので、wtsnjpさんがコメントされている方法が使えます。もちろん、いままでTeXで組んでいたのとまったく同じように別のエンジンで組めるわけではないのですが…

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます．候補となる環境がこれほどいくつもあるとは存じませんでした．たいへん貴重なご教示に感謝いたします．追ってそれぞれ試してみて結果を報告させていただきたいと思います．

Comment: ずいぶん時間が経ってしまいました．ご教示いただいた環境を試してみて，allitが最も適しているように思いました．LuaTeXについてはまだ試せていませんが，導入を検討しています．改めてご教示ありがとうございました．